# Date Comparision fails in Linux platform (Works in Windows) - Oracle 11g Query

Tags: sql, linux, oracle, oracle11g

I have a strange problem in linux.

I have a query fraction

```
end_time > SYSTIMESTAMP
```

which throws an error when I run from linux:

```
2012-12-20 05:03:05,443 WARN  [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (ajp-8109-8) SQL Error: 1878, SQLState: 22008
2012-12-20 05:03:05,443 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (ajp-8109-8) ORA-01878: specified field not found in datetime or interval
```

This works well in windows.

I specifically want SYSTIMESTAMP as I need to get current timestamp of machine where database is running.

The `end_time` is of type `TIMESTAMP(6)`. My requirement is to filter records whose end_time field value is greater than current time. Which function should I use?

Comment: What do you mean by "when I run from linux". Are you using any application like .Net or Java? Or are you using any Oracle editor / tools. Please provide some more details.

Comment: It might be a timezone problem. `systimestamp` returns a `timestamp with timezone`. If `end_time` does not include a timezone this might be the problem.

Comment: what type is "end_time"; the error suggests that it's trying to cast it to a timestamp - this could fail if the NLS settings are different between the two machines